# cs231n : assignment1 Compute the gradient of the loss function and store it dW in SVM Loss

Tags: machine-learning, svm, loss-function, hinge-loss

```
def svm_loss_naive(W, X, y, reg):
  """
  Structured SVM loss function, naive implementation (with loops).

  Inputs have dimension D, there are C classes, and we operate on minibatches
  of N examples.

  Inputs:
  - W: A numpy array of shape (D, C) containing weights.
  - X: A numpy array of shape (N, D) containing a minibatch of data.
  - y: A numpy array of shape (N,) containing training labels; y[i] = c means
    that X[i] has label c, where 0 <= c < C.
  - reg: (float) regularization strength

  Returns a tuple of:
  - loss as single float
  - gradient with respect to weights W; an array of same shape as W
  """
  dW = np.zeros(W.shape) # initialize the gradient as zero

  # compute the loss and the gradient
  num_classes = W.shape[1]
  num_train = X.shape[0]
  loss = 0.0
  for i in xrange(num_train):
    scores = X[i].dot(W)
    correct_class_score = scores[y[i]]
    for j in xrange(num_classes):
      if j == y[i]:
        continue
      margin = scores[j] - correct_class_score + 1 # note delta = 1
      if margin > 0:
        loss += margin

  # Right now the loss is a sum over all training examples, but we want it
  # to be an average instead so we divide by num_train.
  loss /= num_train

  # Add regularization to the loss.
  loss += reg * np.sum(W * W)

  #############################################################################
  # TODO:                                                                     #
  # Compute the gradient of the loss function and store it dW.                #
  # Rather that first computing the loss and then computing the derivative,   #
  # it may be simpler to compute the derivative at the same time that the     #
  # loss is being computed. As a result you may need to modify some of the    #
  # code above to compute the gradient.                                       #
  #############################################################################


  return loss, dW
```

And the solution is:

```
def svm_loss_naive(W, X, y, reg):
  """
  Structured SVM loss function, naive implementation (with loops).
  Inputs have dimension D, there are C classes, and we operate on minibatches
  of N examples.
  Inputs:
  - W: A numpy array of shape (D, C) containing weights.
  - X: A numpy array of shape (N, D) containing a minibatch of data.
  - y: A numpy array of shape (N,) containing training labels; y[i] = c means
    that X[i] has label c, where 0 <= c < C.
  - reg: (float) regularization strength
  Returns a tuple of:
  - loss as single float
  - gradient with respect to weights W; an array of same shape as W
  """
  dW = np.zeros(W.shape) # initialize the gradient as zero

  # compute the loss and the gradient
  num_classes = W.shape[1]
  num_train = X.shape[0]
  loss = 0.0
  for i in range(num_train):
    scores = X[i].dot(W)
    correct_class_score = scores[y[i]]
    for j in range(num_classes):
      if j == y[i]:
        continue
      margin = scores[j] - correct_class_score + 1 # note delta = 1
      if margin > 0:
        loss += margin
        dW[:, y[i]] = dW[:, y[i]] - X[i] # added by jariasf
        dW[:,j] = dW[:,j] + X[i] # added by jariasf

  # Right now the loss is a sum over all training examples, but we want it
  # to be an average instead so we divide by num_train.
  loss /= num_train
  dW = dW / num_train # added by jariasf

  # Add regularization to the loss.
  loss += reg * np.sum(W * W)
  dW = dW + reg * 2 * W # added by jariasf

  #############################################################################
  # TODO:                                                                     #
  # Compute the gradient of the loss function and store it dW.                #
  # Rather that first computing the loss and then computing the derivative,   #
  # it may be simpler to compute the derivative at the same time that the     #
  # loss is being computed. As a result you may need to modify some of the    #
  # code above to compute the gradient.                                       #
  #############################################################################


  return loss, dW
```

I am not getting how the dw is calculated in this, can anyone tell me why they computed the gradient like this. Please help!!

Comment: Hint: Go to the end of the lecture 3 slides where "analytic gradient" is discussed. You want to take this approach and do a bit of derivation to arrive at the code here. (The derivation is not provided in the lecture.)